# C++ visitor pattern multiple components

Tags: c++, visitor-pattern

I got an object tree. In the object tree I store SceneNodes. A SceneNode is usually the base class for other classes.
I want to implement different behavior for the objects that represent the SceneNodes.

The correct Pattern for this problem should be the visitor pattern. I want to iterate over the SceneNodes and want to call different functions based on the objects stored behind the SceneNodes.
But I not only want to allow one object in the object tree to be one component of the visitor pattern but to share functionality.

For example: I have a BaseObject. I can update this BaseObject (e.g. to a new position) and I can draw a BaseObject (OpenGL stuff).
But I also have a Camera object. The camera object can be updated but not drawn.

Here is the implementation of the Visitor Stuff:

```
class Visitor 
{
public:
    virtual void VisitUpdate(ComponentUpdate* element) = 0;
    virtual void VisitDraw(ComponentDraw* element) = 0;
    virtual void VisitOverlay(ComponentOverlay* element) = 0;
};
```

Visitor Component:

```
class Component
{
public:
    virtual ~Component() { }
    virtual void accept(Visitor* visitor) = 0;
};
```

Concrete Component:

```
class ComponentUpdate : public Component
{
public:
    void accept(Visitor* visitor) override {
        visitor->VisitUpdate(this);
    }

    virtual void update() = 0;
};

class ComponentDraw : public Component
{
public:
    void accept(Visitor* visitor) override {
        visitor->VisitDraw(this);
    }

    virtual void draw() = 0;
};
```

And finally a concrete visitor:

```
class SceneNodeVisitor : public Visitor
{
    void VisitUpdate(ComponentUpdate* element) override {
        element->update();
    }

    void VisitDraw(ComponentDraw* element) override {
        element->draw();
    }
};
```

Now I'd like to do something like this:

```
class Camera : public ComponentUpdate
{
    void update() override { std::cout << "Camnera update" << std::endl; }
};

class ObjectBase : public ComponentDraw, public ComponentUpdate
{
    void update() override { std::cout << "ObjectBase update" << std::endl; }
    void draw() override { std::cout << "ObjectBase draw" << std::endl; }
};
```

Ok, so far so good. The problem I have now is that the compiler says "base class is ambiguous". I think this is not correct because ObjectBase is ambiguous because it has two different accept() functions, am I right?

Is there a way to use the visitor pattern so that I can freely anoint the classes with the functionality I need for them?

Here the main function:

```
int main() {
    ObjectBase ob;
    Camera cam;
    SceneNodeVisitor visitor;

    std::vector<Component*> components;
    components.push_back(new Camera);
    components.push_back(new ObjectBase);
    components[0]->accept(&visitor);
    components[1]->accept(&visitor);
}
```

Strange is that I can create the ObjectBase on the stack. I only get the error if I try to create the object on the heap (via new).

Pastebin is down at the moment, I can give you this example code as soon as it's up again.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm not entirely sure, but I think you should separate out some of the concepts you're doing.

As soon as you inherit from two classes that both inherit from the same base class, you need to start looking at virtual inheritance. That might solve your problem. But the path from ObjectBase to Component is either through ComponentDraw or ComponentUpdate. In effect, you probably have two copies of Component because you're not using virtual inheritance.

I would strongly consider using the concept of interfaces. While C++ technically doesn't have them, you can make them, anyway.

And look at virtual inheritance.